# how to call properties of other agents who are connected to each other

Tags: netlogo

Greeting,

let assume, I have one manufacture and 10 customers that manufacture create links with some of them randomly(I call these links "contract-links").

One of the properties of manufacture is "real-cost" and one of the properties of customers is "real-waiting-time". "real-waiting-time" is a clear number. Also, Assume service-cost as a global variable.

To calculate the "real-cost", I need the sum of "real-waiting-time" of customers who have links with the manufacture and then multiply in service cost.

I have a question here to calculate "real-cost". How can I call the "real-waiting-time" of all customers and then calculate the real-cost for manufacture?

```
manufactures-own [ final-costs] 
customers-costs [ real-waiting-time] 
contract-links [ the-real] 

ask manufactures [ 
final-calculation-for-manufacture
] 

to final-calculation-for-manufacture
 let the-manufacture self
 let the-contract my-contract-links
 ask my-contract-links [
 set the-real [real-waiting-time] of end2 
 ]
 let the-sum sum [ the-real] of my-contract-links
 set final-cost the-sum * cost-service-slider
end
```

It gives me a number, but the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason that you are getting the wrong number is that you are doing a lot of setting of the attribute values at the other end of the links instead of getting the information from that link. But your general approach is too complicated - if you have created a link breed called `contract-links` (which you seem to have), then the agents at the other ends of those links are the link neighbors of agent asking. Try something like this.

```
manufactures-own [ final-costs] 
customers-costs [ real-waiting-time] 
contract-links [ the-real] 

ask manufactures
  [ let the-sum final-costs sum [real-waiting-time] of contract-links-neighbors
    set final-cost the-sum * cost-service-slider
  ] 
end
```

This assumes you want the sum of the waiting times of the linked customers. I couldn't work out what the attribute `the-real` is for the links.

Comment: ok, now I understand the meaning of neighbors.
I use contract-link-neighbors instead of contract-links-neighbors and now it works

  `let the-sum sum [real-waiting-time] of contract-link-neighbors
    set final-cost the-sum * cost-service-slider ]`